# Is it ok to return false, to pass ESLint consistent-return error with asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, eslint

I am using ExpressJS and needed to run and pass ESLint rules on my code. There is a rule "consistent-return", which is thrown for code like this:

```
function getUsers( req, res, next ){
  if( req.userIds.length === 0 ){
    return next();
  }

  collection.find({"_id": {$in: req.userIds}}, function( err, doc ){
    if( err ){
      return next();
    }

    req.users = doc;
    return next();
  });//find()
}//getUsers()
```

Now, this code gives 'consistent-return' error. There seem to be 2 possible changes, which remove this error, I'm not sure which of these is correct.

```
function getUsers( req, res, next ){
  if( req.userIds.length === 0 ){
    return next();
  }

  collection.find({"_id": {$in: req.userIds}}, function( err, doc ){
    if( err ){
      return next();
    }

    req.users = doc;
    return next();
  });//find()

  return false; // adding return false passes the ESLint error
}//getUsers()
```

**OR**

```
 function getUsers( req, res, next ){
  if( req.userIds.length === 0 ){
    return next();
  }

  // adding return in below line passes the ESLint error.
  return collection.find({"_id": {$in: req.userIds}}, function( err, doc ){
    if( err ){
      return next();
    }

    req.users = doc;
    return next();
  });//find()
}//getUsers()
```

Please advise which is the right way to go about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The rule here points to a real consistency problem: sometimes you seem to return a value, and sometimes you don't. And it only works because the returned value is ignored. The only point of your `return` statement is to branch out of executing the rest of the function.

Your code here is misleading and it hurts the readability.

Replace

```
if( err ){
  return next();
}
```

with

```
if( err ){
  next();
  return;
}
```

The whole not confusing code:

```
function getUsers( req, res, next ){
    if( req.userIds.length === 0 ){
        next();
        return
    }
    collection.find({"_id": {$in: req.userIds}}, function( err, doc ){
        if( !err ){
            req.users = doc;
        }
        next();
    });//find()
}//getUsers()
```

Comment: Thanks Denys for your reply. I am trying your solution. But the `return next()` I have already used on all of my code. Is it only less readable or there are any other serious drawbacks also?

Comment: Right now I don't think there can be any other drawback than forcing the reader to know that the returned value is ignored to understand what's happen. It can be more and more confusing, though, as asynchronicity is more and more handled with (returned) promises.

Comment: ok. Your code passed the ESLint test. But it's still confusing me. To me, it should return error, because we have `return` statement in if block in the beginning and not after find() function, so I would have expected it to return consistent-return error.

Comment: In express you don't return an error, you pass it if you need to: `next(err);`

Comment: yes I understand that. Even I had this as `next(err)` earlier. I added `return` to such callbacks when ESLint flagged these as errors. I am still a little confused about it. But your solution worked. Thanks :)

Comment: This link - http://eslint.org/docs/rules/callback-return shows using return callback(err) instead of callback(err). Also, if I use `next(err); return;` ESLint shows useless-return for some cases. And if I remove `return;` then it throws consistent-return error.

Answer (score 2):

Let us analyze your code a bit, with some details stripped out:

```
function getUsers( req, res, next ){

  if( req.userIds.length === 0 ){
    return next();
  }

  collection.find({"_id": {$in: req.userIds}}, function( err, doc ){
    // lotsa code here
  });

}
```

Here, inside the function `getUsers()`, there can two code-paths: either an error condition (when `req.userIds` is empty) or not.

Depending on whether the error condition is satisfied, the function  `getUsers()` is either returning something (`next()`) or nothing (actually returns `undefined` implicitly). Note that `collection.find()` is executed in the second case, which itself may return something within it, but `getUsers()` won't know about it.

Now, as the ESLint [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return) state, a function can either return something or nothing (implicit `undefined`), but not both (which is inconsistent behaviour); otherwise a `consistent-return` error is thrown.

So, to resolve the error, both Denys' code and your own second possible change will work. In Denys' code, both code paths return nothing (implicit `undefined`) while in yours, they both return something.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @sayanriju. It is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome! Actually, I myself have started with ESLint just recently, and have faced the exact same problem.